# How to aggregate custom application logs in Spark on HDInsight?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, log4j, hadoop-yarn, azure-hdinsight

**CONTEXT**

I want to configure custom logging in an application written in **python** and running on a **HDInsight Spark cluster** (hence Hortonworks-style). 
HDInsight cluster type: Spark 2.2 on Linux (HDI 3.6), Spark version: 2.2.0.2.6.3.2-13

My requirements are as follows:

- logging to a file
- aggregating logs via YARN so that they are accessible from the ResourceManager UI

**RESEARCH**

I managed to modify the `log4j.properties` creating a custom log appender and a logger that uses it and it writes to a file but I'm failing to make it aggregate the logs.

When I tried to use the [standard](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#debugging-your-application) `${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/filename.log` it got resolved to `/filename.log` and returned a `permission denied` error both in `pyspark` and using `spark-submit` but the file `filename.log` appeared in the RM UI (it was empty though).

The path `spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir` normally should look like this: `/var/log/hadoop-yarn/container/<applicationId>/<containerId>`, e.g.: `/var/log/hadoop-yarn/container/application_1504924099862_7571/container_e16_1504924099862_7571_01_000005`
so the solution I was considering is to set the appender destination file from within the application using either the value of `spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir` or the applicationId and containerId.

In both cases I don't know how to do it in python: `spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir` looks unset (
`sc._conf.getAll()` doesn't contain it) and I don't know where to look for 
containerId, other than extracting it from the `spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir` path.

I managed to obtain `spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir` in Scala thanks to [How do I get the YARN ContainerId from inside the container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724300/how-do-i-get-the-yarn-containerid-from-inside-the-container) but it returns multiple paths so I'm not sure if it is usable.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Is it possible that `spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir` has different values from Scala and Python APIs?
2. How can I read the value of `spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir` in pyspark knowing that I can do this using `System.getProperty("spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir")` in Scala?
3. Can I make YARN aggregate logs from a custom appender not using `spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir`?